# Error 'Error using image Numeric or logical matrix required for image CData' and 'Error in haha (line 28) image(mat) '

Tags: matlab

Why can't I display my image for my 10 x 10 matrix? i want to create a 10x10 square of a chessboard.
This is my code:

```
tile{6} = imread ('tw.png','png');

tile{5} = imread ('twpw.png','png');

tile{4} = imread ('twpb.png','png');

tile{3} = imread ('tb.png','png');
%this is the black color tile
tile{2} = imread ('tbpw.png','png');
%this is the white color tile
tile{1} = imread('tbpb.png','png');

r = 10;

c = 10;

for i = 1:r

    for j = 1:c

  mat{i,j} = [tile{1}, tile{2}];


    end
end

image(mat)
```

Comment: Actually mat is a cell and not a matrix. For matlab this is something very different.

Comment: hmm then what should i do? if i change it to matrix, the image would not load into it.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your code appears to load 6 images and then only use two of them, and you set every entry in `mat` to the same thing.

Comment: @Dicksontan in matlab matrices you can only have primitive data types. Images are not primitive. You will need to work around that. E.g. if all you need is to plot them just stitch them together manually.

Comment: @nkjt i am trying to test whether can i load the 2 images into the 10x10 matrix before i put all of them into it.@bdecaf how do i stitch them together?

Comment: But why two images in each part of the cell? (Not a matrix!) Are you trying to do some sort of combination of them? (your current code just sticks them next to each other).

Comment: really? i wanted to do it as white color tile then followed by black color tile and so on, i didn't know that i was combining them together

Comment: @Dicksontan you are basically stitching using the `[` operator. But it might be clearer to use the `horzcat` and `vertcat` functions.